# I have created a gem using bundle, now how to display some text to the user using this gem ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have created a gem called "quotes" using bundle. Now I want to display some 5 lines of text to the person on command prompt (not on console) say using

```
rake quotes show
```

or

```
quotes show
```

(I am not sure it will work or even possible, but looking for something like this, I am fine with any way of displaying the quotes)

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you want to create an [executable](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables) for your gem.

Create a directory `bin` (actually this could be any name, but the [default is `bin`](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#bindir)), and put a file `quotes` in it which is the Ruby script that you want to run from the command line, e.g.

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Whatever"
# other Ruby code as required ...
```

Now add an entry for `executables` in your `gemspec`:

```
spec.executables = ['quotes']
```

Now after you rebuild and install your gem, the `quotes` command will be available from the command line and will execute the script in the`quotes` file.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I did figured this out after posting the question, since yours is the right answer so accepting it.

Comment: btw, one question, I want to display many lines and paragraphs, how to do it as using 30 or 40 puts statement doesn't look elegant, I tried to use "random text random text .. " but this shows \n and \t at command line

Comment: @iCyborg I’m not sure what you mean. Can you just use a multiline string or a [heredoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents)?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to `puts` the output you want

Comment: Thanks @Dan, so how to run this gem ? say the person put this in his gemfile, how to run it at command line (not at console)